# multiple values in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application, where the admin is receiving requests from multiple users. Now i have created a column 'reqfrom' where i can add single value (name of the requester). and i am fetching this column in array using php and showing the result..

Now what if there are multiple request from different users to admin. ? I am unable to put multiple values (multiple requester name) in one column in mysql database.. how can i achieve this ?? or is there any other alternative. ? i want multiple values in a single column .. Thanks for reading and help

Comment: It is bad practice to put multiple values in one column in a database. You should be using relational tables instead.

Comment: Each request should be a different row in the table, and they each have a `reqfrom` column. What's the problem? Do you mean one request has multiple requesters?

Comment: You should not place multiple values in one column. Instead, you should insert multiple rows, with each row representing a single request.

Comment: can you explain it further ? i am inserting the requester request to single column..

Comment: You mean to say, i should create a table (request table) and there should be multiple row for each request ?? if i have multiple admins for each requests specified to them ??you can take example of facebook friend request (as an example only) - many to many

Comment: @AmarpreetKaur That seems like a bad example, since a friend request can only go from one sender to one recipient, they're not many-to-many.

Comment: but one friend can send request to many friends. and a friend can have request from many friends.. one to many  and many to one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single request can have multiple requesters, you should have another table:

```
CREATE TABLE request_requesters (
    request_id INT, -- foreign key to requests table
    requester_id INT, -- foreign key to users table
    PRIMARY KEY (request_id, requester_id)
);
```

Each requester then becomes a different row in this table.

Comment: Can you explain ? how will i check this requests belong to which admin ??as it will be a separate table

Comment: `request_id` points to the row in the `requests` table. There should be an `assignedTo` column there that says which admin it belongs to. Then you use a `JOIN` to join the tables.